# Fail to use custom checkstyle.xml in my Java application

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I would like to add checkstyle to my Maven Java project which I'm developing in VS code.

I installed VS code check style [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shengchen.vscode-checkstyle). I successfully set the default `sun_checks.xml` configuration, and indeed saw the style errors in my code. The problem is that I'm not so happy with some of the default configuration, therefore I downloaded [this](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml) checkstyle and added it to my project in order to apply my changes to it.

I set my maven checkstyle plugin as follows:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But I don't see any style errors anymore. 
Any Idea how to set a custom checkstyle?

Comment: Someone, please?

Comment: Did you see a hint when executing with `mvn -X verify`?